# Right way to run multiple validation rules on an input value in Scala ?

Tags: scala

What is the right way to validate an input value in Scala ? Suppose I have a password to validate with the following rules

1. Password should not be empty
2. Password length should be greater than 8 characters

There can be more validation rules. But the goal is run all the rules and return a list of Errors (`List[String]`).

The following are the two ways I can think of. But is there a better way?

The code

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

//Validate password using mutable list (Feels like Java style coding)
//Uses mutable list but seems a bit simpler
def validatePasswordMutableList(password: String): List[String] = {
  val errors = ListBuffer.empty[String]
  if (password == "")
    errors += "Is empty."
  if (password.length < 8)
    errors += "Not long enough."
  errors.toList
}
validatePasswordMutableList("") foreach println


//Validate password using Immutable list
//But has to run filter and map on the error list to get desired result.
def validatePasswordImmutableList(password: String): List[String] = {
  def isEmpty = if (password == "") Some("Is empty.") else None
  def isLengthValid = if (password.length < 8) Some("Not long enough.") else None

  val errors = isEmpty :: isLengthValid :: Nil

  errors.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
}
validatePasswordImmutableList("") foreach println
```

Comment: Define "better" in this context as it is a relative term.

Comment: By better I meant building the result error: List[String] in a more efficient way without using mutable list or iterating a list multiple times.

Comment: More efficient in space or time?

Comment: I don't get it! Space or time ... they both are important. I already know which one is more memory or time hungry. I was hoping someone would say "Hey there is a better way of doing this ... [sample code] ... this will require less code, does more & uses less memory" or just say that one of the above two methods are both ok.

Comment: That's code review, try the CodeReview stackexchange site.

Comment: Try `errors.flatten` instead of `errors.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)`.

Comment: @danielnixon thanks ... That's a great tip. I thought flatten was to only convert List[List[T]] to List[T]

Comment: @captain It is, but there's an implicit conversion from `Option`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you should consider is to process an unlimited select of dynamic rules, passed as a list (or sequence) of functions. This way, you can recycle some or all of those rules and easily update new ones in the future.

It would be much simpler to use functions that just return Boolean, however the code below has the advantage of returning all password violations that happened in a similar way most website and applications do these days.

```
object ValidateExample extends App {

  def applyFilters(password:String, rules:Seq[Function[String,Option[String]]]):Seq[String] = {

    //You could use a while loop here if you had many rules, and wanted to stop early

    val temp = rules.flatMap{f=> f(password) } //seq of items that converted to Some(string) only
    temp
  }

  val rule1:(String)=>Option[String] = { s=>
    if (s.length<8) Some("Error in password length") else None
  }

  //same idea different declaration syntax
  val rule2:Function[String,Option[String]] = { s=>
    if (s.contains("X")) Some("Error cant contain capitol X") else None
  }

  //example of a partial function, lifted below
  val rule3:PartialFunction[String,String]={case s:String if s.isEmpty =>"Password can't be empty"}


  val test1 = applyFilters("helloX",Seq(rule1,rule2,rule3.lift))
  println(test1)

  val test2 = applyFilters("",Seq(rule1,rule3.lift))
  println(test2)

  //example passed
  val passed = test2.isEmpty

}
```

Output:

```
List(Error in password length, Error cant contain capitol X)
List(Error in password length, Password can't be empty)
```